# Java - Android Studio App Crashing - The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having trouble with the following code running in Android Studios. The app builds and loads properly and then it crashes when you click the button. It keeps saying "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." Take a look and let me know if I'm doing something terribly wrong. I didn't think it was that hard of an app....

Thanks, 
~Bethany

---

```
package com.example.bethany.bmicalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText HeightInput1;
    private TextView HeightLabel1;
    private EditText HeightInput2;
    private TextView HeightLabel2;
    private EditText WeightInput;
    private TextView WeightLabel;
    private RadioButton StandardRadio;
    private RadioButton MetricRadio;
    private Button Calculate;
    private RadioButton MaleRadio;
    private RadioButton FemaleRadio;
    private TextView BMIOutput;
    boolean StandardChecked = true;
    private EditText AgeInput;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        HeightInput1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.HeightInput1);
        HeightLabel1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HeightLabel1);
        HeightInput2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.HeightInput2);
        HeightLabel2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.HeightLabel2);
        WeightInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.WeightInput);
        WeightLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.WeightLabel);
        StandardRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.StandardRadio);
        MetricRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.MetricRadio);
        Calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Calculate);
        AgeInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AgeInput);
        MaleRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.MaleRadio);
        FemaleRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.FemaleRadio);
        BMIOutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.BMIOutput);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void UnitOfMesureChange(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.StandardRadio:
                if (checked){
                    HeightLabel1.setText("Feet");
                    HeightLabel2.setText("Inches");
                    WeightLabel.setText("Pounds");
                    EmptyAll();
                    StandardChecked = true;
                }
                    break;
            case R.id.MetricRadio:
                if (checked){
                    HeightLabel1.setText("Meters");
                    HeightLabel2.setText("Centimeters");
                    WeightLabel.setText("Kilograms");
                    EmptyAll();
                    StandardChecked = false;
                }
                    break;
        }
    }

    public void CalculateBMI(){
        double BMI = 0;
        double Height1Value = 0;
        String temp = HeightInput1.getText().toString();
        Height1Value = Double.parseDouble(temp);

        double Height2Value = 0;
        temp = HeightInput2.getText().toString();
        Height2Value = Double.parseDouble(temp);

        double WeightValue = 0;
        temp = WeightInput.getText().toString();
        WeightValue = Double.parseDouble(temp);

        if (StandardChecked){
             BMI = (WeightValue * 703) / (((Height1Value * 12) + Height2Value)*((Height1Value * 12) + Height2Value));
        }
        else{
            BMI = (WeightValue)/((Height1Value + (Height2Value * 0.01))*(Height1Value + (Height2Value * 0.01)));

        }
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        String BMIString = df.format(BMI);
        String msg = "Your BMI is " + BMIString + ".";
        BMIOutput.setText(msg);
    }

    public void EmptyAll(){
        HeightInput1.setText("");
        HeightInput2.setText("");
        WeightInput.setText("");
        BMIOutput.setText("");
        AgeInput.setText("");
    }

    public void Validation(){
        boolean requiredMissing = false;
        String StringTest = HeightInput1.getText().toString();
        if (StringTest.length() == 0) {
            HeightInput1.setHint("*");
            requiredMissing = true;}
        StringTest = HeightInput2.getText().toString();
        if (StringTest.length() == 0) {
            HeightInput2.setHint("*");
            requiredMissing = true;}
        StringTest = WeightInput.getText().toString();
        if (StringTest.length() == 0) {
            WeightInput.setHint("*");
            requiredMissing = true;};
        StringTest = AgeInput.getText().toString();
        if (AgeInput.length() == 0) {
            AgeInput.setHint("*");
            requiredMissing = true;};

        if (requiredMissing){
            BMIOutput.setText("* Please fill required fields and try again");
        }
        else {
            //Call the function that calculates the BMI
            CalculateBMI();}
    }
}
```

Comment: just keep the validation method in thread by creating new thread

Comment: Is this the entire class? I can't see the click listener anywhere.

Comment: u havn't specified click listener for the for the button Calculate (or) if u specified statically may i know the name of the method

Comment: That onclick listener may have been the problem. I’ve added it in now and it’s doing much better. Still running slow but now it’s working! I had it calling the function form the onclick attribute in the XML.